# Django rest methodfield if condition working issue?

Tags: django-rest-framework

i want to pass completely and partially paid users in my serializer,but its not shows
,

```
payment_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_payment_status(self, obj):
    if int(obj.total_due) > 0:
        paid_status ={'payment_status':'Partially paid'}
    else:
        paid_status={'payment_status':'Completely paid'}
    return paid_status
```

Comment: What you mean by *its not working*?

Answer (score 1):

Try to return String, not dict

```
payment_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_payment_status(self, obj):
    if int(obj.total_due) > 0:
        return 'Partially paid'
    return 'Completely paid'
```